# Positioning legend on plot divided by par(mfrow) in R

Tags: r, legend

I have my plot window divided using

```
par(mfrow=c(2,4))
```

I have 7 plots and would like to use the remaining plot space to write the legend (i.e. the blank space in the bottom right hand corner)

I was wondering is there an easy way to put the legend into this position?

```
pdf("Plot")
par(mfrow=c(2,4), lwd=2, font=2, font.lab=2, font.axis=2, oma=c(0,0,2,0))
for(i in 1:7){
    image(imagearray[,,i], axes=F, col=grey(c(0:225)/225), main= paste("Plot",i))
    title("Plot", outer=T)

}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Please add the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont indicate how you are generating the legend so i use [`image.plot`](http://www.image.ucar.edu/GSP/Software/Fields/Help/image.plot.html) from the `fields` package. For a [`reprodicible example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) i use the data from the examples in `?image`

You can move `title` and the placement of the legend outside of the loop. For the final plot you can use `frame()` to move forward to the next plot window, and then plot the legend.

```
# data
x <- 10*(1:nrow(volcano))
y <- 10*(1:ncol(volcano))

par(mfrow=c(2,4), lwd=2, font=2, font.lab=2, font.axis=2, oma=c(0,0,2,0))

for(i in 1:7){
  image(x, y, volcano, col = terrain.colors(100), 
                                 xlab="", ylab="", axes = FALSE)
}

title("Plot", outer=T)
frame()
fields::image.plot(x,y,volcano, 
                   legend.only = TRUE,
                   legend.width = 10,
                   legend.mar = 15, 
                   col = terrain.colors(100))
```

which produces

[image]