# Add a legend of colors in image {graphics}

Tags: r, colors, legend

In this example, I have an image with colors and I wonder if we can add a legend of colors. for example : points with `z` in `[8:10]` have color red and so on.

```
x=runif(500,0,5)
y=runif(500,0,5)
z=floor(runif(500, 1,10)) 
xyz=data.frame(x,y,z)
library(MBA)
mba.int <- mba.surf(xyz, 300, 300, extend=T)$xyz.est
image(mba.int, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
```

Thank you.[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222375/positioning-legend-on-plot-divided-by-parmfrow-in-r/28223329#28223329 might help. (or use`fields::image.plot(mba.int, col = heat.colors(12))`)

Comment: Good stuff. Please feel free to write it up as an answer [and accept it ;)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @user20650, the answer is :

```
fields::image.plot(mba.int, col = heat.colors(12))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines. Expand the logic and numbers to suit your needs.

```
col1 = ifelse(z < 4 , "red", ifelse(z >=4 , "green", "black")) 
image(mba.int, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col= col1)
```

Comment: Actually this could change the results, I want to keep this image but adding some legends.