# Out of bound colour scale plot in raster

Tags: r, plot, colors, r-raster, rastervis

I have a raster and I want to plot it using `image()`. So far, I plotted the raster with my own color scale `col`.

```
## read the libraries
library(raster)
library(fields)
library(grDevices)


##random raster object
set.seed(1)
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5)
r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r),mean=2)

col = colorRampPalette(c("darkred","red","lightskyblue","blue","blue4"))(20)
image(r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col= rev(col))
```

This looks like

[image].

Now, I want to plot the all the values higher than the value 2 as "darkred" (initial color from my color scale)

I found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301514/add-a-legend-of-colors-in-image-graphics) and tried the same

```
zlim=2
newcol = ifelse(raster(r) >= zlim,"darkred",col)
image(r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col= newcol)
```

However, I got some error message. It would be helpful if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Mmh... unless you really understand [how `col` works](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-correctly-set-color-in-the-image-function/), I wouldn't start playing with it as you try to do (you actually intend to change the color scale you use, and might end up with non-intended results).

BTW, you error probably comes from using `raster(r) >= zlim` instead of `r[] >= zlim` (but as mentioned, even with this corrected, your result wouldn't be correct).

I seems easier and more transparent to me to instead plot a new raster on top of the initial one (`add=True`) with a single value above the threshold (here, 1 where the raster is >=2) and a defined color (here, yellow to make it visible but you can adapt) and NA elsewhere (so that the original raster is visible by transparency):

```
library(raster)

# Your example
set.seed(1)
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5)
r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r),mean=2)
col = colorRampPalette(c("darkred","red","lightskyblue","blue","blue4"))(20)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
image(r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col= rev(col), main='Original')

# build a new raster with 1 where r>=2 and NA elsewhere
newr = r
newr[] = ifelse(newr[] >= 2, 1, NA)
image(r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col= rev(col), main='Vals >=2 in yellow')
image(newr, col= "yellow", add=T)
```

[image]